# Анимация текста в Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, анимация, текст

Можно сделать анимацию текста в Tkinter ?

Я хочу сделать анимацию для виджета - Label, но не получается.

У меня два варианта : Изменять прозрачность или последовательно добавлять символы.

Вот моя неудачная попытка :

```
if self.StartAnimation:
    self.TextObject = Label(text = '', background = '#000000', foreground = '#FFFFFF', font = 'Arial 20').pack()
    self.Window.after(1000,self.TextAnimation(text = 'Start Animation'))
```

```
def TextAnimation(self, text):
    if len(text) < self.Count:
        self.TextObject['text'] += text[self.Count]
        self.Count += 1
        self.Window.after(1000, self.TextAnimation)
```

код :

```
from tkinter import *

class Tracker():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.Window = Tk()
        self.Window['background'] = '#000000'
        self.Window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.Window.title('Guide Live')
        with open('Guide.config', 'r') as Config:
            self.Lines = Config.readlines()
            self.StartAnimation = bool(self.Lines[0])
            self.Level = int(self.Lines[1])
            self.XP = int(self.Lines[2])
            self.MaxXP = int(self.Lines[3])
            self.PlusY = 0
            self.Count = 0
    def TextAnimation(self, text):
        if len(text) < self.Count:
            self.TextObject['text'] += text[self.Count]
            self.Count += 1
            self.Window.after(1000, self.TextAnimation)
        
    def Run(self):
        if self.StartAnimation:
            self.TextObject = Label(text = '', background = '#000000', foreground = '#FFFFFF', font = 'Arial 20').pack()
            self.Window.after(1000,self.TextAnimation(text = 'Start Animation'))
        
        self.Window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tracker().Run()
```

Как реализовать данную идею ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут несколько проблем:

- Если функцию нужно вызвать с параметрами, то в `after` нужно ее передавать через лямбду
- При `self.Count = 0` условие `if len(text) < self.Count` изначально не выполняется. Чтобы заработало, нужно заменить условие на противоположное.
- Не совмещайте создание объекта (`Label`) и его размещение через `.pack()` (`.grid()`, `.place()`) в одной строке, если вам его нужно записать в переменную, иначе в переменную запишется None (результат вызова `.pack()`)

Дополнительно: рекомендую придерживаться правил именования методов и атрибутов объектов по pep8 - они должны называться с маленькой буквы.

```
from tkinter import *

class Tracker():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.Window = Tk()
        self.Window['background'] = '#000000'
        self.Window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.Window.title('Guide Live')
        self.StartAnimation = True

    def TextAnimation(self, text, i=0):  # i - индекс выводимого символа
        if i < len(text):
            self.TextObject['text'] += text[i]
            self.Window.after(500, lambda: self.TextAnimation(text, i=i+1))
        
    def Run(self):
        if self.StartAnimation:
            self.TextObject = Label(text = '', background = '#000000', foreground = '#FFFFFF', font = 'Arial 20')
            self.TextObject.pack()
            self.Window.after(500, lambda: self.TextAnimation(text='Start Animation'))
        
        self.Window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tracker().Run()
```